# Run Eclipse on Nexus 7 with Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop

Tags: 13.04, java, eclipse, nexus-7

I want to develop simply java app (without GUI) on my Nexus 7 (2012) running Ubuntu 13.04 and I have a question.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Nexus 7 (2012), installed jdk-7u10-ea-fx-8_0_0-embedded-linux-arm-sfp.tar.gz.

After this I downloaded Eclipse Standard 4.3.1, extracted it and tried to run the eclipse executable,but nothing happened.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Java is indeed a cross platform language and should work on any platform... but..

Eclipse uses native libraries for it's GUI toolkit ; it's likely you don't have a build of these compiled for ARM. The actual native binaries are encapsulated in the JAR files supplied ; this is why Eclipse bundles come in platform specific flavours, but the Eclipse foundation don't prepare ARM builds.

If you really want Eclipse on Ubuntu on ARM you'll have to build Eclipse, and it's native libraries, for ARM, yourself. I'm not sure as to how practical that is without a certain amount of research.